# JSON Processing - Sending JSON text string to JSP, how to process in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, post

sendng json data to another jsp page - for testing really.

You enter a JSON formatted string in a text field on my jsp. I submit this through a form request, handled by jquery processing. It is sent to a receiver JSP. I am using the following code to do this.

```
    $.ajax({ 
    type:       "POST", 
    url:        "receiver.jsp", 
    data:       term, // This is a formatted JSON string
    success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                        alert('Success : ' + data); 
                        alert('textStatus : ' + textStatus); 
                        alert('jqXHR : ' + jqXHR); 
                        var jsonJqXHR = JSON.stringify(jqXHR);
                        alert('jsonJqXHR : ' + jsonJqXHR); 
        }, 
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
        alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status); 
        alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError); 
    },
    //complete: alert('complete'),
    dataType:   "text" // xml, json, script, text, html                        
});
```

My question is, how do I pick this POST up in the receiver JSP and do something with it? I have seen somethings with getParameter etc but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easy to send it as parameter:

```
data: "jsonData=" + term,
```

Also you can put it in form input with name="jsonData" and serialize your form:

```
data: jQuery("form").serialize(),
```

Then you can read it in receiver.jsp:

```
<%
    String jsonData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @alexey28. I can now access the data in the receiver.jsp. I have an object, how can I access the data inside the object?

Comment: If you ascing about object that is represented by json - you need to deserialize it first. You can use gson library for this.