# send javascript variable to server and write it to file within the same page using jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Is there a way to send javascript variable e.g:

in  **mychart.jsp**:

```
        <script>  
        var options = {
                chart: {
                       type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                     text: 'CPU Report -    SIU-A-CWDC Server,  realtime ',
                     x: -20 //center
               }
            }
         </script>
```

i realize that this should be json object and already tried to send to server using ajax which sent it to different page i.e **mychart2.jsp** like this:

```
 var data = "op=" + JSON.stringify(options);
 $.ajax({
        url: 'mychart2.jsp',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:data,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

accordingly, on **mychart2.jsp** i tried to do the following:

```
  <%

       String str=request.getParameter("op");
       try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/home/myhome/myweb/test.json"));
            pw.println(str);
            pw.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
          out.println(e.getMessage());
     }

  %>
```

Obviously, it appeared only **null** on **test.json**. Any idea how to overcome such this matter? and how to make it within the same page which is only on **mychart.jsp**? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what is your intention , but instead of writing the json object to a file in jsp , it can be written to file on server side where you make the ajax call to. And then read it in jsp.

Comment: Instead of PrintWriter try using Fileoutputstream. Are you getting the values of str variable? Also try using the `data:JSON.stringify(options);` instead of `data:data`, and receive using options variable.

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8: I'm out of clue. How exactly will i do that?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan: just tried and it didn't work...

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, I misread and answered. Did you check if getParameter is returning the correct text or its null before writing?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono May be this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/json-simple/json-simple-example-to-read-and-write-json-in-java/) will help you. Don't pass json object to another page. Use the same file for processing data.

Answer (score 0):

@Doni Andri Cahyono You can try like following,

```
 var options = {
                chart: {
                       type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                     text: 'CPU Report -    SIU-A-CWDC Server,  realtime ',
                     x: -20 //center
               }
            };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'mychart2.jsp',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "jsonData=" + options,
    });
```

You will get data as object. You need to deserialize it first. You can use gson library for this. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129352/json-processing-sending-json-text-string-to-jsp-how-to-process-in-jsp) may be helpful to you.